# botan development package not found

Tags: qt, sftp, botan

0I'm trying to do SFTP in qtcreator (installed in rpi noobs). I have come across this project https://github.com/sandsmark/QSsh. While following these steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/sandsmark/QSsh.git
cd QSsh
mkdir build
cd build
qmake ../qssh.pro
make (or mingw32-make or nmake depending on your platform)
```

In the last command I get an error saying "botan development package not found".
I have also installed botan using the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install botan
```

and now botan is present. But I get the same error again and again.
What I'm missing here.

Comment: try install `sudo apt-get install libbotan-2-dev`

Comment: @eyllanesc I have tried it. Error is still the same. "botan development package not found"

Comment: I just tested on Ubuntu and it works if I install the package that I indicate. I suspect that the problem is your configuration, your phrase is not clear: *I'm trying to do SFTP in qtcreator (installed in rpi noobs)*, could you give more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You need install builded library. Run `make install` after you build botan-2.
A folder with the library will be created. (For me it was a `C:/mingw/lib/libbotan-2.a`).
Add installed `botan-2` library into `qssh` project in `Qt` (right click on project folder -> `Add Library` -> `External` and choose a file `libbotan-2.a`.

In my case, `Qt` added the following commands in `ssh.pro` file

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../mingw/lib/ -lbotan-2

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../mingw/include/botan-2
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../mingw/include/botan-2
```

Now Qt project can be correct build...
I hope my solution will help!